# Counting subsequences matching a pattern

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, pattern-matching

Given a sequence $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ and a number $m$, I'd like to count the number of subsequences $(a_{i_1},a_{i_2},a_{i_3})$ such that $a_{i_2} < m \leq a_{i_1}, a_{i_3}$.

For example, if the sequence is $(4,2,1,3)$ and $m = 3$, then there are two such subsequences, namely $(4,2,3)$ and $(4,1,3)$.

I solved the problem in two steps: 
transforming the list into a $0-1$ list using

```
binary[list_List, m_Integer] := 
  Table[If[list[[i]] < m, 0, 1], {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

allows us to count the $(1,0,1)$ subsequences several different ways, including

```
SequenceCount[binary[list, m], {1, ___, 0, ___, 1}, Overlaps -> All]
```

This seems to work fine, but now I'm trying to eliminate the first transformation and use `SequenceCount` with a pattern on the original list directly; however the following does not work as it returns 1 instead of 2:

```
list = {4, 2, 1, 3}; m = 3;
SequenceCount[list, {x_, ___, y_, ___, z_} /; x >= m && y < m && z >= m, Overlaps -> All]
```

What is the problem with the second approach? I suspect that the conditional pattern is wrong, but I cannot figure out why. Neither `SequenceCases` nor `SequencePosition` help.

Bonus question: is there a 'better', more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is some sort of pattern bug here.  It appears that, as expected, [`SequenceCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html) deletes duplicates before it returns its result.

With

```
list = {4, 2, 1, 3};
```

Your pattern

```
{x_, ___, y_, ___, z_} /; (x >= m && y < m && z >= m)
```

in the sequence function will return the entire list in both cases as both start with `4` and end with `3`.  When duplicates are deleted only once result is returned.

```
SequenceCases[list, 
   {x_, ___, y_, ___, z_} /; (x >= m && y < m && z >= m), 
   Overlaps -> All]
```

> ```
> {{4, 2, 1, 3}}
> ```

You need to specify which items your want to return so that unique subsets are return for each case.

```
SequenceCases[list, 
   {x_, ___, y_, ___, z_} /; (x >= m && y < m && z >= m) :> {x, y, z}, 
   Overlaps -> All]
```

> ```
> {{4, 2, 3}, {4, 1, 3}}
> ```

However, this presents a dilemma for [`SequenceCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCount.html) as without the [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/RuleDelayed.html) it finds only one sequence, as explained above.

```
SequenceCount[list, 
   {x_, ___, y_, ___, z_} /; (x >= m && y < m && z >= m), 
   Overlaps -> All]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

But it completely fails when the sublist to return is specified.

```
SequenceCount[list, 
   {x_, ___, y_, ___, z_} /; (x >= m && y < m && z >= m) :> {x, y, z}, 
   Overlaps -> All]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

I am of the opinion that this is a bug in `SequenceCount`.  Comments?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I agree with your conclusion, there seems to be a bug in the conditional pattern matching here. 
One question: why do you expect SequenceCount to delete duplicates? Without conditions it does return duplicate results:

    list = {1, 0, 0, 1}; SequenceCases[list, {1, ___, 0, ___, 1}, Overlaps -> All]